# Unable to Map static resource correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My Project structure is as follows

|src

|--main

|---webapp

|----static

|-----CSS

|-----HTML

|-----js

I am trying to return an HTML resource via my controller for links that are directly under root there is no issue but for other links, I am facing problems.

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class HtmlServer {


    @RequestMapping({"/", "/index", "/index.html", "/index.jsp", "/home","/home.html","/home.jsp"})
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("html/index.html");
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/support/{id}/{accessToken}")
    public ModelAndView start(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String accessToken)  {
        return new ModelAndView("html/index.html");
    }

}
```

Here is my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter extending class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("static/");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("static/js/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("static/css/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/support/**").addResourceLocations("/static/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);

    }

}
```

When I open / or /index.html the controller returns the given value and in return i am served the correct resource.

But when I try to use /support/1/xsdda I am mapped to /support/1/static/html/index.html Can someone explain the internals and logically point out my mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: I temporarily solved the issue by using redirect:/static/html/index.html But this is not what I am looking for I want the HTML page to render at  a given URL. I am sure there must be some configurable class that is doing this. Just not able to figure out which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create folder WEB-INF inside webapp and put your HTML folder inside it

- set prefix of resolver to /WEB-INF/HTML/
- set suffix of resolver to .html
- call it by returning "index"

The Servlet 2.4 specification says this about WEB-INF (page 70):

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named
>   `WEB-INF`. This directory contains all things related to the
>   application that aren’t in the document root of the application. **The
>   `WEB-INF` node is not part of the public document tree of the
>   application**. No file contained in the `WEB-INF` directory may be served
>   directly to a client by the container. However, the contents of the
>   `WEB-INF` directory are visible to servlet code using the `getResource`
>   and `getResourceAsStream` method calls on the `ServletContext`, and may
>   be exposed using the `RequestDispatcher` calls.

Comment: I know this. But this does not solve my problem it will still be mapped to /WEBINF/HTML/static/1/asfaf.html.

That's not what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't know why I don't know how but it worked exactly like I wanted. Please share the link to the exact documentation you are referring to in your comments. Thanks!

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1480319492_f198679269b3123ce049c5f752ebe525